# Passing values from list to list when navigate to another page

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

We have one list contain general data we can view this data as rows, when the user select a row, it will be navigate to another page which contain the rest detail of this row index which are in another list.

How could I choose specific index to retrieve the rest detail if this row index ?????

Comment: you need something like `detaillist.Where(identifier == rowid)` to get the records

Answer (score 2):

If you use ListBox control, then on *OnSelectionChanged* event, do something like this:

```
//cast to ListItemObject, in my case "Products"
var fav = (cast to ListItemObject)listFavoriti.SelectedItem;
//send data to another page using querystring
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/ProductDetails.xaml?id=" + fav.ProductID, UriKind.Relative));
```

In your Details page handle query string data with a method like this one:

```
string getIdFromQuerystring()
{
     string queryStringData = "";
     if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("id", out queryStringData))
     {
     }

     return queryStringData;
}
```